# How to intercept errors inside the called module's functions before the caller's try/except

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a (my)module that has about 15 functions that are called by a module(A) that I have no control over.

```
moduleA
    ...
        try:
            mymodule.func1()
        except Exception as e:
            do something
    ...
        try:
            mymodule.func2()
        except Exception as e:
            do something

and so forth.
```

Is it possible for mymodule to catch all errors before they are passed to moduleA without having to wrap all code in every function with a try/except?

A sort of catchall at the module level.

In other words, some sort of error handling that is aware of any and all errors within the whole module and is coded inside the module.

Comment: You can *simplify* and possibly *automate* wrapping your functions with try/except, but you still have to do it. Something "aware of any and all <X> within the whole module" generally does not exist.

Comment: Captain obvious: You can wrap all needed moduleA interface in your moduleA_aloud and use its imports in (my)module

Comment: Sorry madzohan but I do not understand what you are saying.